# How to implement a permission roles/groups system for my symfony2 website

Tags: security, symfony, permissions, acl, roles

**[QUESTION]** This is really more of a brainstorm for anyone who can participate and provide ideas. I would like to start by explaining what I am looking to do, some of my thoughts and hopefully get some good ideas back on how to solve this problem.

1. **[PROBLEM]** I want to implement a permission system for my website.
   The site will have a user login system that will allow an Admin user
   to manipulate permissions for all other users in the system. The
   system would have those basic permissions like view, edit, create
   and remove and maybe a few additional ones. Moreover, these
   permissions would be grouped by a users role. So for example, the
   permissions of create, edit, delete and view would be associated to
   a manager role in the system, but a non-manager role would just be
   associated to the permission 'view'.
2. **[What I have been investigating]** One idea that I have been digging
       into is the use of Access Control Lists. I could create an interface
       that would allow a user to associate permissions to groups and then
       attach those groups to a user in the system. I'm not sure exactly
       the implementation would look with ACLs though.
3. What is the best way to implement this type of system in the
       symfony2 framework?

**[UPDATES]**
As stated earlier but I would also need a system that would allow me to dynamically create permissions for roles and assign them to users. Moreover, I would need to have a simple way to check those permissions in the system to augment how controllers, and template rendering would behave.

**If my post is in error or in the wrong thread please provide me with the correct location to make this post

Comment: The most current solution I have found so far that should work is 
1) to use the FOSUserBundle for manage groups and roles for a user dynamically.
2) Create an admin interface where I can assign permissions EDIT/DELETE/VIEW/CREATE to roles using symfony2 ACL's.

At this point I should be able to assign permissions based on FQCN,or for further granularity the Object itself or its fields. I can access the security context at any point via the container and look to see if access is granted for any domain object/class for a given user. This should allow me to deny access or grant access as needed.

Comment: you should look at Sonata Admin Bundle

Comment: I tried, but the demo fails and the documentation was not clear on what it does, how it works and what it looks like. So I had to move in another direction.

Comment: i have been using it and quite happy with it, but it has some limitations and i should agree that the documentation sucks! but the code does not :) and when i tried the demo worked fine, but installing it can be a pain, i would still recommend trying it out as it would save a lot of time but if you dont feel like it, then best of luck :)

Comment: Do you know the user/pass? I emailed the dev who has been contributing to the bundle on github but not response. When I attempt to log in with the suggested creds it just says account disabled.

Comment: its funny and weird, admin:admin is the official username/password combination it appears some troll banned that :) and the maintainers dont care to look, i would recommend downloading and installing, if that would help...

Comment: hey i just found a working demo here: http://cmf.liip.ch/en took me 4 hours to find though :), anyway you can see it in action here and the admin password is admin/admin, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use FOSUserBundle which allows you to do exactly what you want.

You would create roles for the users and admins.

Comment: The FOSUserBundle alone cannot solve the entirety of my problem. FOSUserBundle takes some heavy lifting out of creating a login interface and provides support for grouping roles. It does not however, provide any means to manager security throughout the application. Basically what I need, it to write an interface that can dynamically create assign permissions to roles and assign those roles to groups.

FOSUserBundle does provide a nice solution to the first part of the problem.I can access the user entity and or override the register new user form it provides to incorporate the role assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement the permission system that you have mentioned above with Symfony.
Create different roles for users such as ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_USER and limit the access to specific paths based on the user role. For example, /admin/* can be accessed only if the user have ROLE_MANAGER.

Symfony's documentation covers all these concepts in detail. You may access the documentation by clicking [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html).

Comment: The current suggestion you are providing is somewhat limiting for my needs and its my fault for not correctly articulating the issue clearly in the problem. I need a way to dynamically add permissions. I cannot use the config.yml because it statically assigns access control to my routes. Where in my system depending on how the permissions are set up for the users, they would be able to access whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a couple of Admin user roles, where the admin can assign and remove roles. As for dynamical creating new roles haven't done that. I believe though that you can do everything required with roles provided

Routes
You can protect routes as Praveesh suggested. You could assign these roles from an admin page with a user loop accessed by ROLE_ADMIN then something like this in your twig

```
                     <td>
                        {% if 'ROLE_NS' in user.roles %}
                            <form action="{{ path('admin_remove',{'id':user.id}) }}" method="post" name="overview">
                                <input type="hidden" name="role" value="ROLE_NS" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  value="demote">demote </button>
                            </form>
                        {% else %}
                            <form action="{{ path('admin_add',{'id':user.id}) }}" method="post" name="overview">
                                <input type="hidden" name="role" value="ROLE_NS" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  value="demote">promote </button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% if 'ROLE_ADMIN' in user.roles %}
                            <form action="{{ path('admin_remove',{'id':user.id}) }}" method="post" name="overview">
                                <input type="hidden" name="role" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  value="demote">demote </button>
                            </form>
                        {% else %}
                            <form action="{{ path('admin_add',{'id':user.id}) }}" method="post" name="overview">
                                <input type="hidden" name="role" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  value="demote">promote </button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
```

And a controller something like

```
 /**
 *@Route("/add/{id}", name="admin_add")
 *@Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function addAction(Request $request, \AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
   // var_dump($user);
    $role = $request->request->get('role');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user->addRole($role);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
}

/**
 * @Route("/remove/{id}", name="admin_remove")
 *
 */
public function removeAction(Request $request, \AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $role = $request->request->get('role');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user->removeRole($role);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
}
```

As far as whether they can create update view delete, I would use ACLs see my question

[ACLs protecting a entities entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928720/symfony-acl-permissionshttp://)

Using ACLs though as far as I can see just means you need to do a whole lot more checking at every route with

```
$authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
  if(false == $authorizationChecker->isGranted('VIEW',$organisation) ){
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
  }
```