# Symfony ACL permissions

Tags: acl, symfony

Am I doing it right?

I have a couple of entities

Organisation

Forms

I grant users different ACL permissions on the Organisation, based on these permission I restrict routes by using the following

```
$authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
if(false == $authorizationChecker->isGranted('VIEW',$organisation) ){
     throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Now inside a organisation a user can create forms, but I want to restrict access to the whole form process based on if the user is a member of the organisation.

So I have the following route 
 for the index view of the forms

```
/form/{id}
```

and something like this for a new form, etc etc you get the drift

```
/form/new/{id}
```

And i'm passing in the Organisation based on the id, i'm then just checking the users permssions based on the ACL for the organisation and using that to determine weather they can see/create the forms

So I'm using a ACL from the Organisation Entity to restrict working with the Form Entity

Is this the correct way to do this? if not, how would I do it?

Comment: Hi, Why you want use the acl to restrict access to the form, you can do it just with a simple if in the controller ?

Comment: because some users might have view rights some might have ... have you seen http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the right way to secure my routes, as I can only secure routes based on the user roles, but what happens when I want to secure a route for an entities entity the user can access. Someone must have covered complex permissions

Comment: I didn't see any problem in your approach, it's your way to manage your restriction, and theoretically it works .